# wtforms get validator type in jinja2

Tags: wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am writing a Jinja2 macro where I would like to get the type of validator (Length, Email, etc.) located in the `field.validators` list. I know that wtforms is able to show the field type (BooleanField, DateTimeField, etc.) using `field.type`, however, is there an equivalent attribute for validators such as `validator.type`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default Jinja2 function or filter to do that. But you can define your own Python function to do what you like and integrate it in your Jinja2 environment.

```
def get_types(objects):
    return [str(type(o)) for o in objects]

app.jinja_env.globals.update(get_types=get_types)
```

Now you can use it from your template:

```
{{ get_types(form.text.validators) }}
```